# What is the meaning of "dubbed"in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

Most humans are now enhanced to be resistant to many infectious diseases. Vaccination is human enhancement. Apart from "anti-vaxxers" - as those who lobby against childhood inoculations are often **dubbed** - most of us are content to participate. And society as a whole benefits from being free of those diseases.

What is the meaning of “dubbed” in this context?

Answer (score 1):

[The Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dub) defines "dub" as follows:

> **Dub** *verb* *[ T + noun* ] to give something or someone a particular name, especially describing what you think of it, him, or her:
>   *She was dubbed by the newspapers "the Angel of Death".*

You refered to:

> "anti-vaxxers" - as those who lobby against childhood inoculations are often dubbed

This means that those who lobby against childhood inoculations are often *dubbed* "anti-vaxxers".  In other words, they are often *called* "anti-vaxxers" or *referred to as* "anti-vaxxers".